# Htaccess for WP blog - shows directory list instead of home page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am running a blog with an htaccess file within the blog directory. However, the blog index page shows up the directory list instead of the home page.

The htaccess reads like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks.
-TM

Comment: Where is your `htaccess` file located?

Comment: It is within the blog directory. We had to create a local htaccess for the blog, as the blog is a sub-directory in another directory. This latter parent directory has its own htaccess, which was creating problems for the blog.

Comment: You say 'was' - is your problem solved? If not, please post the content of the `htaccess` file in the parent folder.